# Can't open Chrome, Brave Browser and VSCode after update

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, brave

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. I've updated package and dependency via `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` command. And then, Chrome, Brave Browser and VS Code can't be opened without showing any error messages. When I open and type *google-chrome and code*, the command does nothing. Even `google-chrome --version` and `code --version` commands can't be run.

1. Removing the `~/.config/google-chrome`
2. Removing the `~/.cache/google-chrome`
3. Purging it and re-install it via the current stable .deb package.
   None of the above solutions work!
   Could you please assist me?

[here is error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edCYR.png)

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: @Jos it doesn't show any error messages. When I type `google-chrome` in terminal, it doesn't show any error message and nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

Please check permission for your app (example: chrome)
`whereis google-chrome`
It will give you the full path like `/usr/bin/google-chrome`.
Now use command :
`ls -l /usr/bin/google-chrome` (replace it with your path).
Output will be like :
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 May 21 08:33 /usr/bin/google-chrome -> /etc/alternatives/google-chrome`

Watch for `lrwxrwxrwx` in the output, "lrwxrwxrwx" means I can `read,write,exectute` Google Chrome.
Please check this on your system.